# Weekly total sums

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, date-range

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database containing dates and a total count per day.

```
mydate       total
2012-05-12      12 
2012-05-14       8 
2012-05-13       4 
2012-05-12      12 
2012-05-15       2 
2012-05-17       1 
2012-05-18       1 
2012-05-21       1 
2012-05-25       1
```

Now I need to get the weekly totals for a given date range.
Ex. I want to get the weekly totals from `2012-05-01` up to `2012-05-31`.

I'm looking at this output:

```
2012-05-01 2012-05-07   0
2012-05-08 2012-05-14  36
2012-05-15 2012-05-22   5
2012-05-23 2012-05-29   1
2012-05-30 2012-05-31   0
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for *any* given date range:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_tbl_weekly_sumtotals(_range_start date, _range_end date)
  RETURNS TABLE (week_start date, week_end date, sum_total bigint)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT w.week_start, w.week_end, COALESCE(sum(t.total), 0)
FROM  (
   SELECT week_start::date, LEAST(week_start::date + 6, _range_end) AS week_end
   FROM   generate_series(_range_start::timestamp
                        , _range_end::timestamp
                        , interval '1 week') week_start
   ) w
LEFT   JOIN tbl t ON t.mydate BETWEEN w.week_start and w.week_end
GROUP  BY w.week_start, w.week_end
ORDER  BY w.week_start
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tbl_weekly_sumtotals('2012-05-01', '2012-05-31');
```

#### Major points

- I wrapped it in a function for convenience, so the date range has to be provided once only.
- The subquery `w` produces the series of weeks starting from the first day of the given date range. The upper bound is capped with `LEAST` to stay within the upper bound of the given date range.
- Then `LEFT JOIN` to the data table (`tbl` in my example) to keep *all* weeks in the result, even where no data rows are found.
- The rest should be obvious. `COALESCE` to output `0` instead of `NULL` for empty weeks.
- Data types have to match, I assumed `mydate date` and `total int` for lack of information. (The `sum()` of an `int` is `bigint`.)
- Explanation for my particular use of `generate_series()`:

  - [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

Answer (score 0):

Using this [function](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_LastDay)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION last_day(date)
RETURNS date AS
$$
  SELECT (date_trunc('MONTH', $1) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

AND generate_series (from 8.4 onwards) we can create the date partitions.

```
SELECT wk.wk_start, 
       CAST(
            CASE (extract(month from wk.wk_start) = extract(month from wk.wk_start + interval '6 days'))
            WHEN true THEN wk.wk_start + interval '6 days'
            ELSE last_day(wk.wk_start)
            END 
           AS date) AS wk_end
  FROM
    (SELECT CAST(generate_series('2012-05-01'::date,'2012-05-31'::date,interval '1 week') AS date) AS wk_start) AS wk;
```

Then putting it together with the data

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab(mydate date,total integer);
INSERT INTO my_tab 
values    
('2012-05-12'::date,12),
('2012-05-14'::date,8),
('2012-05-13'::date,4),
('2012-05-12'::date,12),
('2012-05-15'::date,2),
('2012-05-17'::date,1),
('2012-05-18'::date,1),
('2012-05-21'::date,1),
('2012-05-25'::date,1); 

WITH month_by_week AS
    (SELECT wk.wk_start, 
       CAST(
            CASE (extract(month from wk.wk_start) = extract(month from wk.wk_start + interval '6 days'))
            WHEN true THEN wk.wk_start + interval '6 days'
            ELSE last_day(wk.wk_start)
            END 
           AS date) AS wk_end
  FROM
    (SELECT CAST(generate_series('2012-05-01'::date,'2012-05-31'::date,interval '1 week') AS date) AS wk_start) AS wk
  )
SELECT month_by_week.wk_start,
       month_by_week.wk_end,
       SUM(COALESCE(mt.total,0))
  FROM month_by_week 
       LEFT JOIN my_tab mt ON  mt.mydate BETWEEN month_by_week.wk_start AND month_by_week.wk_end
 GROUP BY month_by_week.wk_start,
          month_by_week.wk_end
 ORDER BY month_by_week.wk_start;
```