# Week interval query starting on mondays

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, dateinterval

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/38fba/2)**

I need to do a JasperReport. what I need to display is the total number of accounts processes, broken down into `weekly intervals` with the `number` of `activated` and `declined` accounts.

For the weekly interval query I got thus far:

```
SELECT *
FROM account_details
WHERE DATE date_opened = DATE_ADD(2014-01-01, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(2014-01-01)) +1 DAY)
```

This seems to be correct, but not `POSTGRES` correct. It keeps complaining about the `1-DAYOFWEEK`. Here is what I will hopefully achieve:

[image]

**UPDATE**
It is pretty ugly, but I dont know of any better. Id does the job though. But dont know if it can be re-factored to look better at least. I also dont know how to handle division by zero at the moment.

```
        SELECT to_char(d.day, 'YYYY/MM/DD  -  ') || to_char(d.day + 6, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS Month
         , SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%active%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS Activated
         , SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%declined%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Declined
         , SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%declined%' OR LOWER(situation) LIKE '%active%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Total
         , to_char( 100.0 *( (SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%active%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / (SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%declined%' OR LOWER(situation) LIKE '%active%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))::real) , '99.9') AS percent_activated
         , to_char( 100.0 *( (SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%declined%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / (SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%declined%' OR LOWER(situation) LIKE '%active%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))::real) , '99.9') AS percent_declined
    FROM   (
       SELECT day::date
       FROM   generate_series('2014-08-01'::date, '2014-09-14'::date, interval '1 week') day
       ) d
    JOIN   account_details a ON a.date_opened >= d.day 
                            AND a.date_opened <  d.day + 6
    GROUP  BY d.day;
```

Comment: Literal date and timestamp values go between single quotes, like `'2014-01-01'`.

Comment: while `SELECT 2014-01-01` *is valid*, it evaluates to `2012` -- also you completely misunderstood what is a literal, and what is a function call -- have a look around here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC -- column values & expressions already have a type, they don't need to be *noted*, but sometimes they need to be *casted* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: The "Fiddle" link is not a fiddle, but another image. Probably mix-up of links?

Comment: OK, there is a fiddle now, but it is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(d.day, 'YYYY/MM/DD" - "')
    || to_char(d.day + 6, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS week
     , count(situation ILIKE '%active%' OR NULL) AS activated
     , ...
FROM   (
   SELECT day::date
   FROM   generate_series('2014-08-11'::date
                        , '2014-09-14'::date
                        , '1 week'::interval) day
   ) d
LEFT   JOIN account_details a ON a.date_opened >= d.day 
                             AND a.date_opened <  d.day + 7  -- 7, not 6!
GROUP  BY d.day;
```

Related answers:

- [Weekly total sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597101/weekly-total-sums/10597845#10597845)
- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql/17282639#17282639)
- [Best way to count records by arbitrary time intervals in Rails+Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576794/best-way-to-count-records-by-arbitrary-time-intervals-in-railspostgres/15577413#15577413)

More about counting specific values:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)
- [SQL Query to Transpose Column Counts to Row Counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797850/sql-query-to-transpose-column-counts-to-row-counts/25797998#25797998)

Aside: You would typically use an [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html) or a look-up table and just store an ID for `situation`, not a lengthy text redundantly.

Comment: Erwin, thanks for that, but I have a question please. in the `account_details` table the column to clarify if the account is `active` or `declined` is a string. for example `"Active - No TopUp Allowed"` and `"Application - Declined Cust No Contact"`. 
How would you sum the string values? something like `sum(LIKE('active'))     AS activated`?

Comment: or even `sum(SELECT regexp_matches(situation, 'active'))     AS activated` where `situation` is the column name

Comment: if I can refer you to.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863179/capturing-and-summing-string-values-from-one-column/25863456#25863456

Comment: @mornenel: I added some more.