# capturing and summing string values from one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bfcfd/9)**

I have this query (with some help from mr [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter)), which prints week intervals.

```
SELECT to_char(d.day, 'YYYY/MM/DD  -  ') || to_char(d.day + 6, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS week
FROM   (
   SELECT day::date
   FROM   generate_series('2014-08-01'::date, '2014-09-14'::date, interval '1 week') day
   ) d
JOIN   account_details a ON a.date_opened >= d.day 
                        AND a.date_opened <  d.day + 6
GROUP  BY d.day;
```

But I want to append and sum other info depending on the value in a specific column

This should be the end result.
[image]

So the info for `activated` and `declined` comes from one string column `situation`.
I tried to capture a `regexp_matches` match value from the column and sum the amount of captures (bellow), but it did not do the trick.

Please, how would you go about capturing and summing string values from one column?

```
SELECT to_char(d.day, 'YYYY/MM/DD  -  ') || to_char(d.day + 6, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS week
     , SUM(SELECT regexp_matches(situation, 'active'))     AS activated
     , SUM(SELECT regexp_matches(situation, 'declined'))     AS declined
FROM   (
   SELECT day::date
   FROM   generate_series('2014-08-01'::date, '2014-09-14'::date, interval '1 week') day
   ) d
JOIN   account_details a ON a.date_opened >= d.day 
                        AND a.date_opened <  d.day + 6
GROUP  BY d.day;
```

**SAMPLE DATA**
[image]
So there is quite a lot more columns, but the only two will be used here. `open_date` and `situation`
`situation` also has quite a few different options, but only `Active` and `Declined` will be used

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/bfcfd/9)**

Comment: you don't need SELECT before reexp_matches. also how are you planning to SUM result of it, if returned type is string?

Comment: I want to SUM the number of `occurrences` or `matches`. No idea, this is my second day using Postgres so Im trying to learn, but the docs is not all THAT clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, but possibly you want to count matches:

```
SELECT to_char(d.day, 'YYYY/MM/DD  -  ') || to_char(d.day + 6, 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS week
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%active%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     AS activated
     , SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(situation) LIKE '%declined%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS declined
FROM   (
   SELECT day::date
   FROM   generate_series('2014-08-01'::date, '2014-09-14'::date, interval '1 week') day
   ) d
JOIN   account_details a ON a.date_opened >= d.day 
                        AND a.date_opened <  d.day + 6
GROUP  BY d.day;
```

Comment: Thanks Bulat, but its just 0s all the way.

Comment: Can you add sample data to your question or set up sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: I have put down some demo data. I will try to make a fiddle

Comment: ah, okay, I see the case sensitivity.. Thanks you Bulat.
Im gonna try to do the `total` and `percentages`, but if I dont get it right, will you be able to assist me later on please.